# FFmpeg - Loss of video quality when using vf setpts

Tags: ffmpeg, video-quality, filter

I created a screen recorder for iOS using FFmpeg. I concat the images into a video which is fine and the quality doesn't change much from the screenshots but when I use setpts to match the video to the audio, the quality drops a fair bit. How can I avoid this?

The command for concatenating the images

```
 "-f concat -i \(textFile) -c copy -b:v 20M -pattern_type sequence -r 25 concatVideo.mov"
```

The command to match video to audio length.

```
 "-i concatVideo.mov -vf setpts=\(audioDuration/videoDuration)*PTS -b:v 20M  -q:v 1 -qmin 1 -qmax 1 videoWithAdjustedLength.mov"
```

The command to combine the video with adjusted length and the audio file

```
 "-i videoWithAdjustedLength.mov -i audioInput.m4a -c:v copy -c:a aac -shortest finalOutput.mov"
```

I am using **Mobile FFmpeg** Cocoapod so I can use FFmpeg in XCode.

Thanks for your help